# how to have single bot framework V4 C# project for multiple bots in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

We have already implemented a bot in Teams using Azure Bot Service(Bot Channels Registration). We are using MS Bot framework V4. Currently we got a requirement for creating multiple bots in Azure for different teams in our organisation. We can create multiple bots in azure portal, but shall we use the same existing bot framework V4 C# project(endpoint) for multiple bots in azure. I referred to a blog and they mentioned that we can implement ICredentialProvider for managing different application ID and passwords validation. But I cannot find any documentation or sample for C# bot framework V4. Could you please help on that and also let me know is there any other way to achieve that if i am approaching wrong techniques.

Below are the steps i have tried so far.
First created an implementation of ICredentialProvider called MultiCredentialProvider as below.

```
public class MultiCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"AppId1","Password1" },
            {"AppId2","Password2" }
        };

        public Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(this.Credentials.ContainsKey(appId));
        }

        public Task<string> GetAppPasswordAsync(string appId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(this.Credentials.ContainsKey(appId) ? this.Credentials[appId] : null);
        }

        public Task<bool> IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(!this.Credentials.Any());
        }
    }
```

Then added the below line to ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs class.

```
services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, MultiCredentialProvider>();
```

But it is not working while execution. Kindly let me know whether we need to provide the endpoint in BotController like below and update the endpoints in the respective required Bot Channels Registration in Azure?

```
[Route("api/messages/{appId}")]
[ApiController]
```

Also please let me know, how we need to handle the dialog for the respective bots after authentication? I have three bots registered in Azure Bot service and need to call different LUIS app for different bots. Is there any way to get the appId in MainDialog.cs class during execution and write route logic based on appId **or** kindly let me know the best way to handle the dialogs for these different bots. Also please let me know how it can be handled using Adaptive Dialogs.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6003

Comment: Why haven't you linked to the blog that you referred to?

Comment: @Kyle : Thanks for the response. Below are the blogs which I referred and tried implementing the IcredentialProvider interface.                                           https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1253

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2258#issuecomment-280506334

Comment: Eric Dahlvang's GitHub comment you linked to already explains how to do what you're trying to do in the C# v4 SDK. If you need help beyond that then you'll need to edit your question to show what you've tried so far and explain what specific points you're confused about.

Comment: @Kyle : Thanks for the response. I have updated the question with the steps i tried so far and also questions have in the approach. Kindly provide your valuable response.

Comment: If you're trying to have your three different bot registrations call three different LUIS apps then they sound like they should be three different bots. Why are you trying to have one bot do all that?

Comment: Are you still working on this?